# Node.js open chrome in full screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I have to open google chrome to a specific page after the server, written in Node.js, is ready.
To do this I've used this code:

```
var open = require("../lib/node_modules/open");
open("localhost:4000", "chrome");
```

I know that exist the kiosk mode but

```
open("localhost:4000", "chrome --kiosk");
```

doesn't work.

How can I launch chrome in full screen from the Node.js server?

---

**SOLUTION**

Close all other instances of chrome and use

```
var childProcess = require('child_process'); 
childProcess.exec('start chrome --kiosk localhost:4000');
```

Comment: Are you sure it's node-related? Does `chrome --kiosk` does what you want when you run it from the command line manually? Also, wasn't it `-kiosk`?

Comment: It's node-related because I've the "main" file of node server that must launch chrome only when the server itself is ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a quick look at the source code for [open](https://github.com/jjrdn/node-open/blob/master/lib/open.js), specifically lines 31, 40 and 47. There you can see that the appname, your second parameter "chrome --kiosk" is escaped, which will result in "chrome%20--kiosk". This makes it impossible to add parameters to the appname when using open.

So your options are to:

- either fork open and add the functionality to add parameters to open
- use child_process.exec yourself in a similar fashion as open so you can prevent the escaping

Comment: I tried with the second option: `var childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess.exec('start chrome --kiosk localhost:4000');` but still not working; it open the browser but not in full screen. Untill I'm without solution I can't fork the open project, but thanks for the idea ;)

Comment: does "start chrome --kiosk localhost:4000" work for you from the commandline, without using node?

Comment: try the following: start chrome --kiosk "localhost:4000" the quotes around the URL are required. Also make sure you don't have a chrome instance open already.

Comment: The right tip was to close all other chrome instances, double quotes doesn't make any difference. Now I have to find a way to force the launch in a new window. Thanks :)